# Is it possible to copy requests as cURL in Safari?

Tags: safari, web-inspector

Achieving the same functionality following alternative steps in Safari is also OK. Or do I need to install either Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: I guess no? Thats unfortunate. When ever im not near an outlet my mac dies because of chrome. Chrome i love you, get your $h!% together when it comes to power. - Love everyone

Answer (score 3):

Open Inspector, change to a new page while it is open, and look at `Timeline` > `Network Requests`, right click on the request you want, and pick `Copy as cURL`